# Nested attributes - Unpermitted parameters Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, strong-parameters

There is a lot of resources on SO about issues on Nested attributes in Rails 4 regarding strong parameters but I don't find any solution on this: (so sorry if it's a duplicate)

I have a 1-1 relation between member and profile.
When trying to update a member with profile attributes I've got this error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: profile
```

Where are my params

```
===> params: {"member"=>{"profile"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test"}, "email"=>"test@test.com"}}
```

My models:

#### Member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

#### Profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

My form:

#### edit.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @member] do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for @member.profile do |pf|
    = pf.input :first_name
    = pf.input :last_name
  = f.input :email
  = f.button :submit
```

and my controller:

#### admin/members_controller.rb

```
class Admin::MembersController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_member, only: [:edit]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @member.update(member_params)
      Rails.logger.debug "===> (1)"
      redirect_to edit_admin_member_path
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_member
      @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    end

    def member_params
      params[:member].permit(:email, profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name ])
    end
end
```

I've tried many things but don't understand where is my mistake.. Moreover in the update method it says the @member is correctly updated (shown ===> (1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok get it..

I think this is caused by simple_form:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @member] do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :profile, @member.profile do |pf|
    = pf.input :first_name
    = pf.input :last_name
  = f.input :email
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding the `:member_id` inside `profile_attributes` which is in `member_params`

so it will look like this:

```
def member_params
      params[:member].permit(:email, profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :member_id ])
end
```

Comment: You need to add also the :id to the list of profile_attributes.